# Remove duplicate in ActiveRecord habtm query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models has_and_belong_to_many to each other:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, :join_table => :tags_posts
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, :join_table => :tags_posts
end
```

And then I have a query:

```
@tags = Tag.where(name: ["tag1","tag2","tag3"])
```

I want to get all the unique posts that have these tags, so I write this ugly code:

```
@posts = [] 
@tags.each do |tag|
  @posts += tag.posts
end
@posts.uniq!
```

I guess it's inefficient, and since @posts is an array rather than a "ActiveRecord::Relation", I can't use all the class methods on it directly.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
@tags = Tag.where(name: %w(tag1 tag2 tag3)).includes(:posts)
```

should do the trick (`%w()` creates an array of strings, so no difference). It loads all posts with the tags in one or two queries, whatever is more efficient in AR's view. And then you can do

```
@posts = @tags.map(&:posts).flatten.uniq
```

to get the posts. `map` calls `posts` method on every tag and returns an array with those posts, but since you have an array of arrays, you want to `flatten` it.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the two tables using `includes` and query on the `Post` model rather than `Tag` so that you get unique posts.

```
Post.includes(:tags).where(:tags => { name: %w(tag1 tag2 tag3) })
```